# Won't allow permission to txt file to read and write in POSIX C

Tags: c, posix

Following code I have done so far. It creates the file but permission access in its properties is no read and write. Thus, when I enable it and run the program again and input the same file name. It works very well. 
So the question is, how do I give access to the file to be read and write in the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#define BLOCK_SIZE 4096

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#define BLOCK_SIZE 4096

int main()
{
   int readfile=-1,openfile=-1, size=0, i=0;
   char str[100],fname[50],new_fname[50];
   printf("Enter name of file to copy: ");
   scanf("%s",fname);
   printf("Enter name of new file:");
   scanf("%s",new_fname);

   readfile=open(fname,O_CREAT|O_APPEND|O_RDONLY);
   if(readfile == -1)
   {
      printf("Open Failed");
      return 1;
   }
   else 
   {
     size=read(readfile,str,BLOCK_SIZE);
     openfile=open(new_fname,O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_EXCL);
     write(openfile,str,size);
     flock(openfile,LOCK_UN);
   }

   close(openfile);
   close(readfile);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you use [`open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) with the `O_CREAT` flag, then you *must* provide a mode. Since you don't do that the mode used inside the [`open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) system call will be seemingly random and you will have *undefined behavior*.